# How to add a hyperlink on angular material tabs?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using material tabs to display tabular data on my angular page. Since these tabs are generated automatically I can't seem to find a way to add an anchor link on the right.

My expected results after adding anchor are like this:

[image]

Code I'm using to display tabs:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight>
        <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                Content here
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
            Content here
            </ng-template>           
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966188/routerlink-inside-mat-tab-angular-material)

you can actually combine them into one like this:

```
<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="/add">Add Identity</a>
```

you'll also need to make sure you're using , instead of .

documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation