mat-tab-link is not properly underline the selected tab in Angular
<div class="navtabs-container">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/" routerLinkActive ="active" #home="routerLinkActive" [active]="home.isActive" >
        Home
      </a>
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/executive_dashboard" routerLinkActive ="active" #executivedashboard="routerLinkActive" [active]="executivedashboard.isActive"  >
        Executive Dashboard
      </a>
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/food-beverage" routerLinkActive ="active" disabled #adminsection="routerLinkActive" [active]="adminsection.isActive" >
       Admin Section
      </a>
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/lifestyle" routerLinkActive ="active" disabled #myrequests="routerLinkActive" [active]="myrequests.isActive">
       My Requests
      </a>
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/helpview" routerLinkActive ="active" #helps="routerLinkActive" [active]="helps.isActive">
       Help <mat-icon matListItemIcon>contact_support</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>

I am trying the underline the tab when it is being selected but the actual result I am getting is by default home tab is being selected and underlined , even if you click on other tabs.

routerLinkActive ="active" looks like you have an additional white space which should not be there

Did you take a look into this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008661/5470544

Yup I went through that , but this was different. It got resolved by assigning correct router .
for home I was giving the default router as routerLink=" / " which was causing the issue making the underline  stick at first tab.

Thank you for the response @JSONDerulo :)

I think the issue is that home route is always active, which then leads to not allowing other tabs to be active because just one tab can be visible at a time:

Angular Material tabs organize content into separate views where only one view can be visible at a time.
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

The home route is always active because by default active route matching is not exact and cascades. Hence /foo and /foo/bar links are both active if current URL ends in /foo/bar. Or in this case, if you're in /lifestyle, / route matches because / is part of /lifestyle

Active route links cascade down through each level of the route tree, so parent and child router links can be active at the same time
https://angular.dev/guide/routing/router-reference#active-router-links

To solve that, you can use { exact: true } as options to the RouterLinkActive directive to only match home route when URL ends in /:
<div class="navtabs-container">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/" 
        routerLinkActive="active" 
        #home="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="home.isActive"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
        Home
      </a>
      <!-- rest of tabs -->
    </nav>
</div>


On a side note, I think you could replace routerLinkActive="active" by just routerLinkActive. Given styling will properly be set after setting the [active] property binding AFAIK.

